# JavaScript - Compare Strings and Remove First Character From One of the Strings Until They're Equal

Tags: javascript, for-loop, string-comparison

[Link to CodeWars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/shift-left-1/train/javascript)

> You are given two strings. In a single move, you can choose any of them, and delete the first (i.e. leftmost) character.
>
> For Example:
>
> By applying a move to the string "where", the result is the string "here".
>   By applying a move to the string "a", the result is an empty string "".
>   Implement a function that calculates the minimum number of moves that should be performed to make the given strings equal.
>
> Notes:
>
> Both strings consist of lowercase latin letters.
>   If the string is already empty, you cannot perform any more delete operations.

My problem is that I'm assuming you need to loop through both strings in order to continue comparing whether or not they're equal. If they're not equal, increase counter and loop through again.

But I'm not sure if I'm looping through both strings at once correctly.

Is `i < (s.length, t.length);` the correct syntax?

This is what I tried:

```
function shiftLeft(s, t) {

    let sArray = s.split("");
    let tArray = t.split("");

    let counter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(s.length, t.length); i++) {

        if (s === t) {
            return counter;
        }

        if (s !== t && s.length > t.length) {
            sArray.shift("");
            counter += 1;
        }

        if (s !== t && t.length > s.length) {
            tArray.shift("");
            counter += 1;
        }

        if (s !== t && t.length === s.length) {
            sArray.shift("");
            tArray.shift(""); 
            counter += 1;
        }
    }

    return counter;

}

console.log(shiftLeft("west", "test"));
```

But it is giving me an incorrect value for the test in question - the counter for `"test"` and `"west"` should only equal 2 and this is returning 4.

Is my logic wrong or is it the syntax of the for-loop, or both?

Comment: Algorithmically I would do something much more simple.

Compare the end of both strings and check the longest similar string. In this case would be 'est'. The sum of remaining number of characters of both strings is would answer.

Comment: It should be `i < Math.min(s.length, t.length)`. `(s.length, t.length)` just returns `t.length` because that's what the `,` operator does in an expression like that.

Comment: @4castle Okay I went ahead and changed it to `i < Math.min(s.length, t.length)` - the function is still returning 4 so there must be something else wrong with my code....

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge that makes sense - I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An issue with your code is that at the end of each iteration, you are updating `sArray` and `tArray` without updating `s` and `t`.

Then, in the next iteration, you are checking if s and t are equal, which will never be the case, unless they were equal since the beginning.

So, you should be updating `s` and `t` as well.

---

Also, in this part of your code:

```
if (s !== t && t.length === s.length) {
            sArray.shift("");
            tArray.shift(""); 
            counter += 1;
}
```

Shouldn't the counter be incremented by 2? (I see this as being two steps, but that's up to you).

---

And on a side note, using `s = s.substring(1);` to remove first char should be muchs impler than dealing with arrays...

Below is a snippet using your own logic, but addressing what I mentioned above. Hope this helps!

```js
function shiftLeft(s, t) {

    let counter = 0;

    while(Math.min(s.length, t.length) > 0) {

        if (s === t) {
            return counter;
        }

        if (s !== t && s.length > t.length) {
            s = s.substring(1);
            counter += 1;
        }

        if (s !== t && t.length > s.length) {
            t = t.substring(1);
            counter += 1;
        }

        if (s !== t && t.length === s.length) {
            s = s.substring(1);
            t = t.substring(1);
            counter += 2; //shouldn't this be 2 instead of 1?
        }
    }

    return counter;

}

console.log(shiftLeft("test", "yes"));
```

**Edit:** It turns out your for loop condition was not correct. The counter `i` keeps on increasing while `Math.min(s.length, t.length)` keeps decreasing and getting closer to zero, so the loop will stop too early. The real logic we want is to keep looping until one of the strings becomes empty.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw with the counter in the last `if-statement` - yes, it should be 2. I did not know about the `substring()` method - that makes things much simpler. 

Unfortunately this still doesn't pass all tests in CodeWars. I noticed that `console.log(shiftLeft("test", "yes"));` returns 5 when CodeWars says that it should return 7. I'm not sure what is wrong...

Comment: @HappyHands31 I found another flaw. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you - that make sense.